# Deposit before multisig setup is complete?

Tags: multisig

Is there any point during the creation of a multisig wallet that funds can be deposited into the wallet or is it only safe to make deposits after the final step (The exchange)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deposit funds into a multisig wallet as soon as you have completed the multisig wallet `make_multisig` process (in the case of N/N wallets) or have completed the `make_multisig` and `finalize_multisig` process (in the case of M/N threshold wallets).